# Unrecognizable code in mysql log (not slow log)

Tags: mysql, logging

I just ugpraded mysql from 5.5.24 to 5.6.16.
I disabled innodb in my.conf. Now after mysql start, after some hours, I always got some Unrecognizable codes in mysql log as below.

Anyone know how to fix it?

```
140214 09:37:05 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /ssd/data/mysqlpid ended
140214 09:37:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /s/data
tcmalloc: large alloc 1532624896 bytes == 0x242a2000 @  0x8013750dd 0x87e0b3 0x872e99 0x5b895d 0x6435ab 0x5a7d26 0x5a12cf 0x801151000
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_TRX' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_METRICS' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS' is disabled.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Warning] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'loose-innodb-ft-inserted=0'
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@mysql' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Warning] 'user' entry '@mysql' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@mysql' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 1 event
2014-02-14 09:37:08 11536 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.16-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 0  Source distribution
2014-02-14 15:03:48 11536 [ERROR] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(1392361422 - `chipbbshell`.`pre_common_searchindex`.`dateline`)'
Thread a3c93800 has exiTthTrThread 9TeTaTThread a5ec7000 has exitehThread a37e7Thread a479b400 has eTheThread 971478Thread Thread a5040000 has exited with leftover threahTThread a3cTa0dhrrTT9TThxd0Thread 9TdThread a3c91000 hhreTeTThreaddhread a5ehTTa T400 haseThTha 2TThread ar56TThread a4dbbThreahread a4TwThThrThreadTTh4hThread 9743c800 has eThread a4ad980TTrc7c00Threas exitedThread ahxh-specT  TTTr4hhTheTT0f5c00 has exiThread hread 986TThreT TThread ahhde80rT0hThread 96ebT0TdTrrrearedhTTTahTThTTrhT5aTThTThaa e0rT TTThTThTThhaThread a4dbac00 has exiteThrhThTTeTTTTrTTTTTTraihTTThTriTTThhdre9T5hT1TThhrhThhTTTTThhrrTdTThrTradh rae5eTThrehahTThhrraTT TaT3rrheeaaddr haT5r0eThhrhhrrTeTTehcTahTrheTThhTrhhhTThhTrheraTThrTThThrhTrahdTThhwTdrT2h7r3TcTTeTahTThhTrrTeaaTddT TThrrreTThTeharhTrheharTeTadhhirreeaa7 9ah5T1h0TThhhrrrre4adtrTrhrTThhrTThhTThhTThhhrheT Tahhrde aaTahdraedahheT TahrTeharddhaTh3r0r0d hae4T ir r6edTThrraeeaah rTetae hTr9erah0ah9TrceTThTrrreeaadh daeTahdh r9TTTh1rrhrreeahehereTehThhh2rhT9Treeaard daerr4rar5erTTrrcheTahTTrhrrteeaardehhrr0h0rdh eae3hceh3r4efhrha eleeTdTeeTih39c29caehThheraeT hrhrreT h9Trh9rehcr1h0aTa8eb 89heh4dr T hhcehTreehhhdTrhrrhbr4 0Treerareeher eaa3rcecr efeeeaada eedaTdrfe1aede ada Twhi e0edT herTehaa5d2r7e add daraah0a dh ahrrehaar5erae f a aTdheraeeta3ac0T4eea5 sh rsrTeha8d9 hardaeed haae6aTde aae4ahdd  9a dr eeahTd1h5rdr4e aeTTrde a9a9d7Thhr eThe4abd4 4teha 9l45495rhaedaad5  aad3ar eeedh9rrheharreracT040eraedareeeadexer4eaada  a0 0a 5aTfd0a5Tada dTe i9rreeahd5rce3ahdrde r9Tdh h9rf5565eare0eaadhhdrdear7eda0aa0dahe dct8dba4t0ara haa5d daresa aadaerce9aad4fd de xwiitde d  e9 eeeheadr aaadd eddTrhedr3edr dT hrTa 9fdTdh3edaedaeda a9d  r e acdi7twdehataehb9r0 hhr Thh rti tae4e4da7drae0aadc 0e0a rheaahd0d9 8d10h   laa5dda   cad4 1ae5ard  ar8e0he5rTe aadad lThh9T 4a25799eea4hd  9rdd  haraeaaaeaadrderaedh ae5ardrae4adda era1 5aedc Ta 539e5aed8a0a0e x5iaaaahdeaacd9  a 9adehae4h6ahdr  99d5a9da aa3acddc505 8lrhe0 reeh60f02a hae 0a 4eace80aadd9 d 0 50d rhdaad8 fad7 0eh3rhaaa3d d  59e5ae4ah w4iahdao5eeahaafdtroe90a67ad1 fah5 raa0d3aa5d  re9a5de e35 c995a57rae5ae ad3 car8a30a0r eeT 0rd79addehda3 7b4d769rae f935a0449ea840000  hh9hdrd3da a 000a0bdberaeaahfrdedaac4 ddaaad0d8a3e da0e05 8h09b7c89 7acd0   0ac2T  aaedc93s80s04fa4d0bhar0haa sa5c7 8074850c01 bhaa4s0  2h0 0d 01a4b5d6T4adsh65ecf989 c9a9r7hdaa40000a95b4897hr4eda da t1a0e 5abd90aa4d9 hdr ear3a0d000hh a7se  ehxairt cr98eadaa303 30705 4ahded9  a 4dbc8  70ca99d5 8a3 3h3e4ad8da 0s eaa aa daah5e0aa5de ae3c40 4s4crd6 4at304580a6ca9503aca95era 2e0x0  5heh4 aad0sTddr6era8000f050rheeard4 9a8 0a8c080ba4dd0 de0aa0d0  ahsa a0  aaf490 2a8s4 84 00409ca00bt0db5adaa r5a23f7aes7 0e0x0908 8 0a05s5 eeaads  a5d9 ca0add0c0804 0400 0e a0de 0a0daa4 0 0e ac rae609 e0h55c957dd7cc8hxahs3584 7995e6xr9e5a5d0edb4e0d0r890e0  956e 4hrae aad4a59t0ea3 e5135c8a08 0d0e ah6a05 0dh aa44aa4r0e0ardx 0d  f700  9h7a6seda7 ahs6 v rTeh 9a4h7a9b9h 8a030ce30ca 4ahd9i5tae54x9ide90r4e7a9db  eedc 0bca9s8  ass ce002 xrehad8394e78400 0h rh d4  080a4097a48h0a hhaadr0e a070e a5se62e9h ahs9 ca 456ei8d0 090d 0h5aasr e 5e5h7cs0 a06 he1a4c0  hhch5a 40Tfx aa0 0aa0fh9r 3a 3ea8a08a23708 0e00  aed850 s2 4e aadaa0a03 ch9a91xbs8  5e0d 4 05xdai4t5e4xa0s04ab 0hsa  eah5c85527d68e7a3d0 0aa400h rhehaads8  4e4xc76 hxa0s8e4a50 09ed5a9458ace6x9ce694e 6df 5at ohd5 0axes ahcah8a 0909 3i5h69v  awdi cc8ac0si7taehda dt78e7d0 4edx0ad905 53as50ch0h04 0h 7h1a4e8a0s0 ae3x0i7ta400eai9t8eida40e0ass a 59 cc000 0aae7a7df ca050e s xhaa3s3sahi tce090a chh8 de00  0ac9  dsx  e xiictae0 6a04h6 td1dh0c30c08af 2a2ia 3ecx b h7bhaa4i i 6 6h0a00 7 aas30cc90s00 5 eec 9a8040000e sh9a9  ewxi0tahca4s9 4h0a0s 0h sc de 603h3a3s6abca09000a0d0 da d0a 5e5x0idtd  9w 4a5sxaida 590ahs tfe8de0ette1a89000d 0ahxeiat3es  ieef8se 0a ehaa993 2h0adsh as   eexxat40c763ac810208 9h9 6eax5i0a0 ceaxwhir0 aedabsst s7 3ac5d0 dwcics0 0fie74a4509050s0  iet7488090040800 0h0dhc 0h  xhe4xddd 300a05i3teea sehx0 ae3xsi0twaisthhhdacfecx s00 xrh ah a4s0 s  ed0 dw 7hae08606x1xlie ci3t3ed dda da 0c x 56 05ddc09h6a0se9d4aeti04 w c4a3 ie0taesa dh aat5ahsa esr 4 0elietf5th7s1eecd6cc9980be0hl08 690d0iic3998759a74 0e da0aa4s9 hexaet s 4750d07s4 0h0a ie9xd890hi wbth5a  whct634th e00 0s  0e xhaisb0a ahvedx  80ea0s0a0tte 3d7 0w  h00ei6t s8t0oses e5x wah5 04 s  eex0i 9sv et0  dh ewcidt h0 hdh a e0d  h7xeht0ha2o0s0 aes0  cseavietr8 5a0 4h8i0a da 5a2060hea0sc  eesxwfitthh 0l40tee de9xax be8x1ixadh  wai9tahd46000e xlxdiead4i644c06da 4waishdt0b0s  tex a05ta0xa s  13h7h34ic 2hatceads  wai rhe0x0 00es  eh0i4 c9ldedfaa784 0i0tdeleirt sh fetxoevce 4 9heaf080i  0dd ew8ittah5 tle008w0itta0td ix cd htbe400s9aesx 6e6xhiatie  lhaaad0 0w0ef 1w8is001 aex08 ihs4h0a0s8 0hwt300 ti9c9f0 xsi ietxrats4 0e00w0ie9xx etdh 0wehd0  wes0x iatse  5eftae 9x4i teeid heexxiht  l eefxhi1ecteeo 4eei8ixt  h5a8s3bass  xeixth1 9haxsi tt8xaict8e0d0e be4x3 d47a08 taitae i0hdi t2ets00tfdidi ii osc  hh  lveee64 a 0h ieeedd 0eixtit40weidhe dl  ewteoiv0w30400  oevf9d8 h8thrteeada07 sh aetx3c8r u000 0hchaadi  0l swe0 h 0e010400waia xsi3ect90bhtaet0  s 0hxasss09 74a7f8bit0eh0d3aist  ee  re0x tah0x ih a beaher5rt etiht0h  hlaetis0 sehda s4ro ihtah0a s da dw0iitthat0ee0ac 0hhaaseh0i0dt aws0 2wv4d0  0x0hweheitt e 0h0i ahsa  swxei0ts4w94c0 aewxei 0450eh4c  7 axs00t h5i3t3x0ee iet1e xh iwsi ts  eeh0ahhr0ssxdi taeida h2 8 0x0ss heexeixte dxetaetehirhh  laexeixttdo-vsepthe d0 swe0i  h sl6e1 8s3x8t0rseixdxdiihthiaasiht sh0atseeexi t he  wtsa0c  a 5sheaxsw  dd tweri d 8wtdi0t 3lae fettd6 aw0ict8w0 0  tss e4x9i8t0edr  0e  hee0i tthwiithhiasl0x ewal 0idt 4weed0 0 itteed0 0we fitho  l ewx tdx9ift0e dh alss 4hie6d0  weixt ht 0hih0a5se ded hhah0d7tht wittxtteede e e xe xdt0x iwtaei teeedi twwt9h4a0st0hsrhe19iel4 hhaae dexdaasxiit hl0e hetd  0h0e tehx0i  exchih0asash et0laedi  i0af 0e0e  xe5xsf ehfttht eldeiha se fs0se thha0s ieidt ewd -e xeidac582acs0d0h i0xo2ehxai-t7ic 8h ewx4 ix h  cs d0 80sdesxtiwaashiita sw whieexi atlhe f t se  eht hi slhia shdds feef ttxesd lsx 4h9aeh0i0t hh x 3aatesx xeixli 000 ohexftt x4aiittlhe h4atet0 ehd lleeftthowtif 9lsvdi ieteaofvfetto8vherrs0t0w0ietah e 00xee ic0  0i0 -fw ihi7ila elxeie0xetst2aiwthh tlhi twxa hxtietaeedd  dw4xteexd sw iet elebdsso vhetrf tt 04t iwtret0h0i tih 9  le sl oher1ittfetdeahs   ewxaist aeso eeaxci0 d fwtiodh-istdefeaetxeedd 0 0e xevheeexx d xtietd dhet0s0 0ti hwdp e ee hhas  lvxeiheifd osvtde  hertexietdxtited  l5 ilfetoovvee iitt  79dt oaw vwetrw xowhfa ewxcitdiwf0weixx  hsarseiaedt0hsowpiescsixfiihcesse 4lwxxitl 4e ew i0t iereoe  ilti te dh  ittta   i whiithhit hwsiliatsef0t0s  hlar0 e8a0s0iwvfietfatwowv eer e f-fsxplaewvaedtifetfotixwaf5tso teeddwett3eittxtihtdh0vdwxeidw4i0t hch0eeoevxetevt0e dheafid0eilaeift teei tdedh  c  wweeexhic2h  awse fettvdh  werr  6db 0i  etxiilttahs xweadi thhht hds  t hiecr r8 5h al  wii0vwhwiit edxhi tei9eteotdh  slaeefxtieiwesw ietwwde8fcr0ttlhdxde ew iwii thv 0e e0iheherxxl  vo -ss p0eecxitf ewetdoehta h awspst ei dh0ciiehhade i rwttoeveecst xei tiie4x8iheail tw0 etresitih0 ewrxad  e iawtaxdihtlerd t hh0e0 0  aede te x0  etro0 0dt8eli0ttdiftcxo titlets 0vtexd twehe  lheettfdlivtthe4d tteirtx herieftthef0t0t  ses  ee ewr eldtoevaewfww0i0t hh  ll er te vthh6ecfttherx d heteedi xwiiwtxiitt0ir0hielde0axf iltdhe fefh shha tlh do hw0i0txiitt ettftteodxha e wh0fi dltehe o fhtaos  d  ltldiht l0 elvelt hirietavstlh vee rt oidd  weievxleedf v df0latteat ca fltehfrdeaiishhtroh ahs0  iht wttheerdtwerw0i0tadse  ehx elds  iitteixtarwhahw ahie dtthietfetdt hw ithlx ltr  tho i  lheafse wlee0v e iat h ilrtwhirxohioeieifttwd -hshwaevdw fwtiotvht hi trh  tesftettrexde pw hi flteod  odehia thle tifww sxieoxhirsftest oevee  ewxietthi fttooww vsihhxdiehti0rt hx iltehffvte fvtx es  weexxiitietdhsiewlee  xsevxta eedileftthxtlovxei oda hi tvt ewhlaeifoteoeoeffvtdt hs w ho vxteehveiex ietrhtreofvtd  twxllea vwehralslees0r  ttrhh rtth atsetdoietwhetthhieifttieldodvtoevfet hveevtiht hxaeitehd  ewxrahs eld dliwtr  w i l oltivteerd   a   tiats0 0atdoetf t tweefde hhtihieex0i0t ehta stirl fwtetrofetitt rilrrehatde-dt eodewe xiiatehv ereeeodv ew ido0itrhi  aetaadt-hrhe arx ledeeedixoifiewaidt hh evr e aldt elde fht ol taere-ds pdaia a hwriehadf rttteo ri ttrsephefctivfee essp iet e adv-eslretpvr  tow iedd ttvrde-eedhhtfleex l-vrvteea dhief t xl eaaevxeiwtifarwaldtseowva shtt dhehw iittx ihe sh teo-xfaet wtirlo ve ts plttohv elxe fr f wwii fsieidtithxahs ew iotvhereeaatlhesfpfetetfhtrrsetaeehra stivheh-iswfilre ftt5eloewwiitrde ahddp iltteheafietrht oetfeeiefat-esrptso dt- s ietche- sweflteofvdeerx io vpde cewtittihfcweiatdh  t he flt  wsi hertdev etchhe ceexaihhl elreiftri weothh tlhe ido r lltshfitd frtixdlrlvehe fetxoivf slhhw ilt rwlreelteesdehdrre eteheef t4-t eii wt htto vtefiirl etiedc ovvotst dle st eefthhd -lheef tdetto ewttoev tlfetfrx w ifttp itherre tel  hori etdh rwhiwfxoirt eivteiweie aidf-dv-estetoov ra fwiitthh di htch9x elrhtitt hthf rldw iht ht  deaethsepf tfht dtto rh  tlhefd- soetfoti tlttooveetwhrr  verleeardt-osvetfhhreexfeleeiteofvt ofviec he  l-osvpeescrhleelfctiolftfvsvpe fitehfadf-ihct efietcherdr twteorvatteofv etsx iteldc ewrifttirtdh twhcopvaede re ervpehrr veexoivteest herteh eriedf -weieroevrfcxiir   xdieeptefvitrerx it  le dl da ttfhtrhtt otlhe wchtxe elfetfete cdiafeixtiet ettescpie4ve  r drwtidddviteoflro xeteeerr wleelrwietfrwt owdvhtvoe etherfeo rdiltatdd-hvc iwf-tore x althwrifrv  trht hesdpde0t0e rwteorlefaaehfil--cseplteoeefrt oivtehtth   eetthh-eetxtlhvreeiith oeh  to vdtelf  htreeeefitocd tahddda c fltihtteafe slpeicci vailtthe alvoeewai twtaef-tseorffidc- rteoxv ivvdh rwei iplttetixtldsedsdv-xshfeteehxrietct ceiecaodv-ereexei ohvwrodva teat daaadsi v evaeti f4iveeiatretdr eewr  ie recxdiftrthhf tdi tivt etrh  afhtredalfhtrltofvretdaeorieff toovrefvteht  daedpweiitt eeif td fatiotchraaddp-tshi d wh-i-areicfhiai-eerdrtdeadidfaiisidlheraehierwcirho ple dd-tpteetdhsrteoftt dw idtshp xld o v steheartda p odtfhciicfivfato peeectl  twtoecdrteeardle rl  teatfelrers  e htro at fdt-rs eeeetro ef -tihe rt eercitcciife ttrrl hv etphwi  wiihftroehaadt-tsrptehia  tefaidi c4te-tscetfhvdt-h4 cwrt htraeuahrrehtr  lteca  ha rtetaocvfvte acvda-o ddt rcevhe dratesepietlee wwii pe e iwtoavoede-hsdtvohvnfe xcde-caass padt el-sirhetrltefatthh  leerf tthh rhetarfrt ih efts-pveeerff tidr elreteh-tsepe fahceitoh-h-fssecdifttdh-rda dwlheffivcl pdaveefdto  dt tsfsdrfedhevrs-ptlherehfi tperprr iacadu-teiot hw ietteiitfai cteheeaeore ctdt ewaifloefrsopweit alleeffcaildeafttfrvsepvecctir  ilfeeft edothieoooaefwlitthhrteecd  ewfietaar ielwriettrrieta htrhe eo vaefeeo-rs phdr-eesaevaeerctifri ct hdreera o  aeaafdf-tdt elrtistftfetr  v e e aterpvdtro ttelawd hrhcrapr  he-edw-4   svwhtbde-hteosidcaahdr-asdtc4  edresro efrolvteecottrd idfartoaoev c4i-fsipce efttoc t ftsctwhl effahhcottvherrdi dre dtaetrhaafdveashtrpeaa df-dsa
thpaedcdi ilvecf - ar  ttrhtfriuccittohvedfitoodv erph-taidcd ddp at dtc tfataesdi-ar  aerirtre a ooarv otvhe atehsrrvtesrtprteeaftpeepretchaicres  eeddrfeihdusrpeefctforvedf tehatdotvehf cwip  taardeftloc t hdrce at trdehce cadtehshwrsetadepeocvniofe -cdi-vflie-otvtesiptetd--aswvxeirdf-es ilteiaftlpeesrrwtirfseoart erd at-v dee atdeff twee
sst-reoivcr lfeucaetsohseprruf tfoavfeir-wsipr vhetchtoovrc  ieiitche ete rw4u eteefav eer edr-oeri thadv0p0efrlitiotlhr herreceepepweeceedt-esdhattotd-faa taif tpoifttiodvcora tt esrpl etfraetoinhtha-e- sepceorvphtterr -tiidfti cevcedcr adta thac iaf-isioleara r da fttar civcec thrietrs-hev- therhiiffciil aercerdiciirtd r-ttohslsepve s pd -fter 4 destructor iterde h-rs-r ere etciisfpiastdrdd-aanlaeho vaecr edraevfetrofcts pdsddvetfet tcoitt vfeiloeeelhe  tds-
sfatdh- htieffecxrhflthpfeifcii-ipcr ldetfct stvltehr retcaipoeva titehcvlrpeeirf  4t hirfeiacvreeraadc- tsepeere f4iitchfrteo v eidrrl ewfatlhe h dcri fpiwtawaid r ateefoivctvocxtiad fharerfates
f ttehe rircc idiecferatdrpcettt i ctdfeiece idae ca fhsfhh -tadd-rtaaaaodsrttaforv etehahd eeaadi vihtrfetard -vipa -atfs p cdraetr teae rdo-eheecxiiao avfrw ittehda-ttai tertaraddeo fa dcvteohi-r viecrereeacd atthvveerraid it   apaepcratdp-e-asd  wdirtehha idstscatta df-ttrer4s hdae -hwrresrs etptehfr tworidt-pshlrerfrvsev-ds-ecfa do-te aadffti tthi psevteartst esictedcevlhircdi- s  tfhht hhr fdiaffitr ewalreefpeeaiwsiedra rtuihadt-aedi-dscctir socveovv harfitpae cti faiecr  dwtittehhssphefcii  hadf-woivetpe  ldd-rselredf-rse f dleeeftthdreesafdteofepdeapdt-hhrrvefaieotaciitfh-fstooveestoevveerfpeetceiaaatpae fa ffsae-aedt-fittrisctdc-iprep etahdrehaedra -de--i-ech  aattlas rt sssppiefoiorfai etaddade-assppeeerh c  dd ahcarh do-acs  edtarcuiccd a fcd -di-cpdtsat hl tdha rtstsdis-iaf4ieldtfhtrher e thtrhoretcotfdtl eafttfcp iefri t oircepveesdp-osvpea4t adharae-aad   h cioftar  atawspdeecai rppetfaiae4c idroptdhfepifeicci ccit elrea 4t r edaideeacaefctitfhwiie-cpieec fdioc  septeriupc clietfvtera dtihfrirfacrfr eha e itp--s sdpafttepoe vadtpthaicito iaclr fp iacfvtaesfriacecaf whacd -cs pr  terd -erf ttohvretddetra edfarrtrefaahir eaerc -ts p ddca -vh -csic trt pitrh d4d tdaafdr-4 ttef at aatfctt hcv edrfeaeeieeiclpt crtea- sep-escphersepasdptehcfitfoprlaadfa edcai leecc da-ctpseecxicsepcefaiecr  dtaitca rsiieedrteichdda-iftehadda-  dhetrf f4eaca  dfadthesittasrp rdisipcededc-csipfeffit4-feurteristce slaeaittierrt larvvtsara stphfrdea tceiefai r ae ecri afea dw-iteaa fatfhteca e4etfe chi tadht  e pief-iidc- sdpaeaf tdeattaa4e cdireicslitepre fftetchi flteefdisaafddsr  acfitifteof4i cr  dtafeaedcfhicfhiacd -dsar foiacp earo vdeersct arieca pdeattatiocvr 4afeiccpd tto r dd-a eda  edaaets-rsah rt-taht re dt-hcrearhetfr uap ivlaedl- settchtrra dad ed4-  evreprr i r  ed ateaaeiidf-fe-rs prviet oevdetetaorp etcatfhtoeru ca aa taedrt4t  fddaerrppsfrc i fcfcfdsedra vidicf fdo4r adtrectle riactr  4p fiihwdteert ecetienesipffeerr a4d -dsep-taaedceisctfreu clvfitdedrrfec-  c4o vca  dwetcpi a4atffteafetse radfattavfotttiric4  tdsihct aai w-iitfhefecreetrecf ehrho-dfuts rtthe rtepoe dd--euc data after 4 destructor iterations
ions
cific data after 4 sadafaitherderaar-tt4tctieietae civccicaarths pcd siterecr attaf dssaatsa etehtihotnfseel tihirtsrpeaadd
-lfevfetdtfar iaifdirdc hdieisf tdhateci tehi s4terouv adoc 44tt- aefrta ee-da t-dseectaearesr4cti-f4i of itcrc ctrai cr edrsd-eeri tr4r vtucr esatfttpe irations
ffaaedielcsip eacfcdecss  dtts td fd
dheaaiirpatde-- poeae ftceisstt4dfotfearreeca fdst vadh edsasiofhii -eva ce aisca d4- rs pdeaat eaafde-4s e  tahfrt epee ciiuddea ra ci ai-rsfpfe tdas faafrevsetcrcutdcetsctt a4  reatfotvear4  4d eatfae aadc-tstfrs dher e thcco aetacrcu c itto-est-esair s paecr-raif dfridsstp daddra etrd rtcd-a rteotr foteeartrac i ilreca a odnastehtfiasrpiefc appeeseu  t4a  peeie  dd-du
sfcutahdrlaci4tddpftvear  ara t at ittr ta frtiedaercie-hs peerfdfseprd et esetarcs fdiact  aictt eiatct dsrctc fadfte-4sedrh raetceifsiitfo4u acfitcsitfridadetfdferr edp 4d -esdtitfhitaat afttfaipeeaphe-cr4oor itfeirdi4efciie redr hirfarf a4t adee setaaef-asta4affspretc-4hf t t fdftttaerrpaetciirfttc tioc etrhaitaau ra fstsftirha-t ptec srt eerureucoerraesrtdade tei fdia taadotnhpitsaicidc- sct4  cfeirtf itcfcorn sftdrfuid-4t tdae altea  cade-tse-rsdrototv  4d trduceprtiroursttorru cdteoardr ed atac  oivfoeve  rr d teccftedaataafnas tt-hsrp rl rfutc tteicaiaf-etr4u ct edtaetsi el4ccdcedaadteas taratcac fst
deattochipt ocr4ctiohiafpuacdt-osrfviecr   t4hdcdaae acd sds4w idafrtaetaectiatirlraa t 4drshhfftaettaopre ai eardi-oitre cic irfe fau coard trtu c tio ora 4t arf4r  ae aa  aahsdrsepaedn-tft rdeasctrri t-hpai pdeic ci a   acfiri  4i eaifo4naedrer4ipcefattedrt  eirer
ra ees -ospietiecetre et fdst
ra ees -ospietiecetre et fdst
errea ddceistde-tsip ea t4taafhtte rtd-isce c t  eeseprf iihsthatteafircp4r-4s pnea fcsu e re -4peroiiaicct feircd ddeusitpaiccef tscdtracdi-fdoerrfiefc ardd-asr-pshpss ts aiitcstpeeecsiado-nedraetarefaat e4 4aefsctiuo vfrcr auicrttidt-esdttfaefrf t4roun s-do 
dtoifo r  astt
ttsace sdvedcerdeaat aa idaadtareeftie-cdiafriucc teotrrrsutc4t oitcdaesrtci ttiilac iasfct  fia 44   dioaontiocaaa eedcitcrnfvee cetar fiarf tietrt4rfarc fssttredes
utrddetfes t eer  ifipcri ttfrfc
pe
sathfaifdtaeurtartt odtttdoircfd aersceatdsa
arnu4scrdt wuac trrarrd t eruadfsip eaeu4  ddaa- stth ftiac  itcocrrdatticrs4cttocra ffttesc
f ttefriecro eoarit t4rfiitointi td adtdaaeteas tar4at aittc sttrr u4tofacd edsntcara 4fviecrea  ierrus rdeaotradceroaera a-  feator iterations
structor iterations
pecific data after trteaddetsett d-eidfre osirriupcdareeaferepitcdsrpte aad  coae 4d ed eiittaetrta rafd  ff fitccdctdrautiadfai  c  ddeattaa dea r  adeerei-airt tthhrrna4d cortasate
aepteosi
pecrf  4sr ai tidcd tuaa  raeisdec ddeastt4e riatt iiseaa t aeesad etsat ca  riuiae ri f4t cfuefre ers c4tro c4ftttctt-
etaarre iae  ce dt-eeadtrtaotred acrtdtaittietrfu s eta44  ddeispcific data after 4 destructocfvterradeer4 a4  adsapttrpfetceersaritioorn uiutrt e-rsherce ei f4seecsrt dt-rscppefr rouif-taafdsdeuciieofntf t4aeahtc i4fr uidfoesestsic an  ad4
 eartatarcaerstedrnh st
ittee-rscurde-rsoorsipreecfivoetrr ut taatdt-t
osv e raornaspn4si
ofdctsfrtra  4oara dc-icfdiact edra taofrtiace fttceci tir  li ue rpu cdteescaitadtaad ci tf
 u4p tdetfsct rspueco 4dttaa freart sdtcriufrr
f4areart-isopsec a4e ddtet
dottc4tnosdaa oedreetsatrf -4s ruupcetcde iiciet pier   4ifc  idtd airstphtrcdaaitcari fii c  ed eaardu cpoceaafdd-eptiecr urctttae
rraitseoce satoeira   d i rctidtatiacpsupctc   dscttreur-ecaiaedssppred ahdoev tfa tdetrctencsi
iifoudacdtdo rd  odtact   att4artretc idfsito t4er aafo  hart4d tfetrf t4e aiefcticcuecoars pietc-tsfvttedrnsaptetcofreecsiofnast
e errcahttaaf itsettrourc  eepcttcaioerf t4ca adta taf  adfatteara f4ifcn aafofatuos atfft odteitrian-astpaado enaortcu44 f rdstctaeiaftri   f tarfetseornro tttete-s rc4  rivpeo4vicst aa sa
dciiteeco rd diertead -adfettivtahia fota- aittau erfussfeioceocra dt fcaicc eetr eircsitaetraa  a t etshdaidc ta ti tsetiict errodd adtaatdaeeers tdtiaffeiiipuerei re  teasdsetrriuataotrea oiaddea4tr fcfirf icc  ddaatptdiec utri ftaat acrcrtsot rcutcces e oi4r dstre t  atctaf taafttrtodreotrr -rsu4ratt4t4e s o4aaf  deprena drersotreerecrir odn
srtrherpeet4teacfitres tfr daafuscdi fcrauiccr udaa a t4a  due tdosceiafeictnts  el ocrrufni ca idraoanri est
```

Comment: why have you disabled InnoDB? Please also note you've got bad option in my.cnf -  unknown variable 'loose-innodb-ft-inserted=0'

Comment: The reason is I'm only using myisam

Comment: About @akuzminsky comment, the messages unknown variable 'loose-....', are only a warning because when an option is prefixed by --loose, a program does not exit with an error if it does not recognize the option, but instead issues only a warning. Note also that as of MySQL 5.6.21, the --skip-innodb option still works but it is deprecated and will return a warning when used. For 5.7 you cannot disable innodb.